# United states City coordinates to plot using plotly

Tags: r, maps, plotly

I need the coordiantes(lat/long) details for all the cities in US.

Is there any package/function?

There is `map_data()`from `gglpot2` package for **states** and **counties**.
For states there is `map_data("state")`
and for counties there is `map_data("county")` that has all the required coordiantes details.

Similarly is there any function for US cities? I tried `map_data("city")`. It didn't work.

Comment: The `maps` package has a list of cities with Lat-Lon

Comment: please include from which package comes your `map_data function`

Comment: @G5W can you please tell how to get all cities at state level of USA?

Comment: You're actually after a data set, rather than an R package. [Here's one](https://simplemaps.com/data/us-cities) that seems to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `ggmap`

```
ggmap::geocode("New York")
        lon      lat
1 -74.00597 40.71278
```

Comment: I need for all the cities  at sate level. Because there are city names that are common among states. Just like how map_data("county") gives all the counities at sate level.

Comment: Have you checked the other parameters of the function ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't get it. I tried `ggmap::geocode("Abbeville")`. It outputs only the coordinates of the city in LA. But the city is available in SC as well. It misses that information.

Answer (score 0):

`maps::us.cities` might interests you. It has lat/ long of all US cities having population greater than about 40,000.

```
library(maps)
data(us.cities)
```

Comment: I already checked that. It doesn't have all the cities in USA. It has only 1005 observations.

Comment: [This](https://simplemaps.com/data/us-cities) has a very comprehensive list (over 38,000 cities and towns). You may want to check this out.